# Can't target first-child

Tags: jquery, html, css, addclass, children

I'm trying to target the first child of this code, however it doesn't seem to work, I've tried with all the different methods I could find but none seems to work. Any idea on how I could fix it ?

```
<div id="main">
<div class="page">
    <p>random 1</p>
</div>    
<div class="page">
    <p>random 2</p>
</div> 
<div class="page">
    <p>random 3</p>
</div> 
<div class="page">
    <p>random 4</p>
</div>
```

```
$('div#main').children('div.page:first-child').addClass('current');

.page {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
visibility: hidden;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.current{
visibility: visible;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: In jQuery 2.1 all works fine - [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/U7LmH/) and `first-child` is a valid [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/). What is your bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to use children() here. [EXAMPLE}(http://jsfiddle.net/U7LmH/1/)

```
$('div#main .page:first-child').addClass('current');
```

Comment: his current way should be a bit  faster, if he got rid of `div`. but that's irrelevant i guess.

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for your help, strangely it doesn't seem to solve my problem here : http://jsfiddle.net/t8C5f/4/

Comment: Wow, you have a lot of code there that we weren't privvy to when you posted the original question. The selector works, as many have demonstrated. This has something to do with your CSS.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jay, thanks to you I could fix it and improve my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('div#main').children('div.page:first')
```

or also try this:

```
$('div#main').children('div.page:eq(0)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
$('div#main div.page:first-child').addClasS("current")
```

should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Your code should works: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ca9G/)

Make sure you've included jQuery properly and put your jQuery code after including jQuery.

Lastly, try to wrap your code inside DOM ready handler:

```
$(function() {
    $('div#main').children('div.page:first-child').addClass('current');
});
```

Comment: Hi Felix, thanks for your help. I tried it on fiddle and it doesn't work in this code http://jsfiddle.net/t8C5f/3/